How to sign a message using Safe?
I cannot verify the message using Safe. I have a recovery feature on my contract which creates a hash of some data. I need to verify it against a safe signature. The verification scheme is in the code snipped below. Can someone please help?
bytes32 msgHash = keccak256(
            abi.encode(
                RECOVERY_METHOD,
                block.chainid,
                address(this),
                nonce,
                newOwner
            )
        );
       
msgHash = hash.toEthSignedMessageHash();
        

if (IERC1271(safe).isValidSignature(msgHash, signature) != EIP1271_MAGICVALUE) 
    revert InvalidERC1271Signer();


Hey Shivam, could you try again following our guide? Let me know if it works. https://docs.safe.global/sdk/protocol-kit/guides/signatures/messages

Hey @ValentinSeehausen already tried using it, doesn’t work. Also tried signing via the verify message page on scrollscan. Doesn’t work as well.

Hey @shivam-agraval, then I can have a deeper look. Are you able to provide more context on this? Can I see the whole code of the smart contract? And potential utility code you use? Safe Smart Accounts sign messages using the standard EIP-1271 signature scheme.

It would especially be helpful to see how you pack and sign the message off-chain.

@ValentinSeehausen Hey, the codebase is here
https://github.com/etherfi-protocol/cash-contracts/blob/main/src/user-safe/UserSafeSetters.sol#L129
You can check out how we pack data and check the signature, thanks for the help
